# No such file or directory bbox,label,conf = cv.detect_common_objects

Tags: python, image

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
import tensorflow
     
image_path="D:/paper_data/user_picture1/10503.jpeg"

img=Image.open(image_path)
img=np.array(img)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

bbox,label,conf = cv.detect_common_objects(img)
```

When i run the last code 'bbox,label,conf = cv.detect_common_objects(img)', python shows me the error:FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\vicky\.cvlib\object_detection\yolo\yolov3\yolov3_classes.txt'

Since this is my first attempt to analyze pictures and my purpose is to retrieve the objects in the picture.

My question is 1. whether there is any package can be used to achieve my purpose 2. what does the error showed above mean?

Comment: Have you moved your Python files around?  The OpenCV object detection installs extra files containing its models.  This is saying those files are not where the installer put them.

Comment: How can i find the original Python folder? i install python in D:// , now i cannot find the right folder containing Python files. Is there any right folder name?

Comment: I suggest you uninstall and then reinstall the OpenCV package.

Comment: `pip install -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple --trusted-host pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn opencv-python`    i used this code but it still did not work and showed me the same error above

Comment: i have checked my Python folder in D://. There is a package named opencv_python-4.5.5.64.dist-info in the lib folder.

Comment: Sorry, it's not OpenCV that's causing the problem.  It's `cvlib`.  Try `python install --upgrade cvlib`.